# Real-world combinations with repetition question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I use Apple Music. Every 4-6 weeks I put together a very long playlist and put it on shuffle. When songs are played, I delete them from the playlist so I don't hear them a second time on another device.

The playlist shows cover images for the first 4 albums in the playlist. I've gotten curious about how to calculate the **probability** that any given album will show up in the playlist (songs from each album are always together). *Edit: Here's an simplified example*

| # | Song | Album |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Track 1 | Album 1 |
| 2 | Track 1 | Album 2 |
| 3 | Track 2 | Album 2 |
| 4 | Track 1 | Album 3 |
| 5 | Track 1 | Album 4 |
| 6 | Track 2 | Album 4 |
| 7 | Track 3 | Album 4 |
| 8 | Track 1 | Album 5 |
| 9 | Track 1 | Album 6 |

The playlist shows images from Albums 1-4. When all the songs from one of those albums are played, the image will be replaced by the next album in the list. If song 8 hasn't been played, that will be Album 5. So what's the probability that song 8 will not be played before all the tracks in any one of the earlier albums?

I got this far: if an album with x songs is at position n in the playlist, and there's one song from each album above it, the odds of picking one of those songs in r tries is

$$1-\frac{(n-x)!(n-r)!}{n!(n-x-r)!}$$

Since r=4, this is manageable. But I don't know how to modify the odds when there are multiple songs from other albums above the selected one. So I'm looking for help on a problem that isn't for my homework--thanks!

Comment: It seems you're actually trying to calculate the probability, not the [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds). I don't understand how the playlist works. You write that "songs from each album are always together"; but then you talk about "picking one of those songs" – it's not clear to me whether individual songs or entire albums are randomly selected, and if the former, how does it come about that songs from each album are always together?

Comment: @joriki I edited the post to hopefully make the problem clearer. Thanks for taking the time to reply!